# Как задать для стрелок Owl carusel свои элементы?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

написал вот такой код

```
    $('#block-views-complexservice-block .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    margin:0,
    nav:false,
    smartSpeed: 400,
    merge:true,
    margin:15,
    responsive:{
        992:{
            nav:true,
            items:3,
            navContainerClass: 'slides-arrows',  
            navClass: ['slide-prev','slide-next'],
        },
    }
});
```

но что то меню не не кликается

Answer (score 0):

Используйте свойства **navText**

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/stufu/pen/rwKyJw) пример

Пример с **SVG**

```
$("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
     nav: true,
     navText: ['<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 11 20"><path style="fill:none;stroke-width: 1px;stroke: #fff;" d="M9.554,1.001l-8.607,8.607l8.607,8.606"/></svg>','<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 11 20" version="1.1"><path style="fill:none;stroke-width: 1px;stroke: #fff;" d="M1.054,18.214l8.606,-8.606l-8.606,-8.607"/></svg>']
 });
```

Пример с картинкой

```
$("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
  nav: true,
  navText: ["<img src='myprevimage.png'>","<img src='mynextimage.png'>"]
});
```